# Finding the global maximum of a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, integral-transforms

I've the following code:

```
R = 1;
L = 100;
c = 5;
\[Omega] = 1;
Uin = 1;
Plot[InverseLaplaceTransform[((Uin*\[Omega])/(s^2 + \
\[Omega]^2))*(R/(c*L*R*s^2 + L*s + R)), s, t], {t, 0, 
  10*((2 Pi)/\[Omega])}]
```

The output gives:

[image]

> How can I find the global maximum of that function? So I need to find the time $t$ where the function on the y-axis is the biggest. I can see it is roundabout $t=17$ but how can I use Mathematica to solve for that point?

Comment: `R = 1;
L = 100;
c = 5;
\[Omega] = 1;
Uin = 1;
NMaximize[{
  InverseLaplaceTransform[((Uin*\[Omega])/(s^2 + \[Omega]^2))*(R/(c*L*
         R*s^2 + L*s + R)), s, t], 10 < t < 20}, t]`

Comment: @wuyudi I want to find a general solution, so I can not use the known values for $t$. In general do I not know the boundaries of $t$

Comment: How about NMaximize[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[((Uin*\[Omega])/(s^2 + \[Omega]^2))*(R/(c*L*
        R*s^2 + L*s + R)), s, t], t, Method -> "RandomSearch"] which produces $ \{0.0108751,\{t\to 17.0718\}\}$?

Comment: @user64494 That does not always work. This gives a wrong answer: R = 10000;
L = 340*10^(-3);
c = 6*10^(-6);
\[Omega] = 2*Pi*f;
f = 50;
Uin = 33/10;
NMaximize[{InverseLaplaceTransform[((Uin*\[Omega])/(s^2 + \
\[Omega]^2))*(R/(c*L*R*s^2 + L*s + R)), s, t], t >= 0}, t, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch"]

Comment: @user64494 Because it should find: $t\approx0.0248259$

Comment: This is a hard case. Add the options MaxIterations -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 150 and you will see $ \{5.48196750366060835509719455776018628887372271163587831317370347492576023969559001598770481295965724255359105914337643471909792517794215991836246788618,\{t\to 0.00620567500560892404523664869787608816752217435540476222180172707547399982638356313088049089142787730514001828972528199385226553781455932698814446557099\}\}$. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 Again that is not the maximum, the maximum is found at $t\approx0.0248259$ because the function is there $5.62561$. So using your method I find not the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, add the options MaxIterations -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 120 and you will see $\{5.62561067741309626590052309852478986788130219846742362487032174518871057527009742613177843434235379903319716896695511815,\{t\to 0.0248259253443082058494006651008781830467028532802701739604031425552943586777327087282381003444770833553257725809095823626\}\} $.

Comment: @user64494 Works that method for all cases? Adding those two options: MaxIterations -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 120

Comment: Sorry, I stop that empty talk. Every command has its limitations. That's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

R = 1;
L = 100;
c = 5;
ω = 1;
Uin = 1;

f[t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[((Uin*ω)/(s^2 + ω^2))*(R/(c*L*R*
         s^2 + L*s + R)), s, t] // FullSimplify

(* (1/259001)(-100 Cos[t] - 499 Sin[t] + 
  5 E^(-t/10) (20 Cosh[t/(5 Sqrt[5])] + 509 Sqrt[5] Sinh[t/(5 Sqrt[5])])) *)
```

[`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the function to adaptively sample it

```
plt = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 10*((2 Pi)/ω)}]
```

[image]

The points in the function are

```
data = Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];
```

The peak data point is

```
peak = data[[SortBy[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]], Last][[-1, 1]]]]

(* {17.0672, 0.0108751} *)
```

Using this as an initial estimate, the function's maximum is then

```
FindMaximum[f[t], {t, peak[[1]]}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {0.010875072207704462201, {t -> 17.071813673825464498}} *)
```

or

```
Maximize[{f[t], 19/20 peak[[1]] < t < 21/20 peak[[1]]}, t, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {0.0108751, {t -> 17.0718}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

With additional information, that second derivative is negative (which NMaximize should know anyway), you get the right result.

**Edit:** 
I think, this works, because second derivative reproduces the Sin and Cos term with same but negative prefactor, so that NMaximize can eliminate these terms.

```
NMaximize[{f[t], D[f[t], {t, 2}] < 0}, t]

(*  {0.0108751, {t -> 17.0718}}    *)
```

**Edit2**

Even `Maximize`does the job easily if you restrict t a little bit away from zero.

```
Maximize[{f[t], 10^-6 < t < 100}, t, Reals]
```

You get a root expression for t which you can use for further analytical calculations.

```
{t -> Root[{-998 E^(1/50 (-5 + 2    Sqrt[5]) #1) + 
  501 Sqrt[5] E^(1/50 (-5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #1) - 
  998 E^(-(1/50) (5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #1) - 
  501 Sqrt[5] E^(-(1/50) (5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #1) + 1996 Cos[#1] - 
  400 Sin[#1] &, 17.0718136738254647391}]}
```